# Why is there an Invalid Write here (Valgrind)

Tags: c, valgrind

I am coding a shell. When I execute it like this `cat /dev/urandom | valgrind ./myshell` to run some test and see if I don't have any segfault or other errors, `valgrind` sometimes tell me that I have an `Invalid Write` in function `my_wordcpy` at this line `tab[++j] = str[*i];`

It doesn't happen every time, but it does happen, and I just can't see why. Here is my code :

```
static int      count_words(char *str, char *sep)
{
  int           quote;
  int           words;
  int           i;

  i = -1;
  if (count_quotes(str) == -1)
    return (0);
  words = 0;
  quote = 0;
  while (str[++i] != '\0')
    {
      if (str[i] == '"')
        {
          if (quote == 0)
            quote = 1;
          else
            quote = 0;
        }
      if (quote == 0
          && (is_cinside(sep, str[i]) == 0 && str[i] != '\t' &&
              (is_cinside(sep, str[i + 1]) == 1 ||
           str[i + 1] == '\t' || str[i + 1] == '\0')))
        ++words;
    }
  return (words);
}

static int      my_wordlen(char *str, int *i, char *sep)
{
  int           quote;
  int           j;

  j = 0;
  quote = 0;
  while (str[++(*i)] != '\0')
    if (str[*i] == '"' && quote == 0)
      quote = 1;
    else if (quote == 1 || (quote == 0 && is_cinside(sep, str[*i]) == 0 &&
                            str[*i] != '\t'))
      {
        ++j;
        if ((quote == 1 && str[*i + 1] == '"') ||
            (quote == 0 && (is_cinside(sep, str[*i + 1]) == 1 ||
                            str[*i + 1] == '\t' ||
                            str[*i + 1] == '\0')))
          {
            if (quote == 1 && str[*i + 1] == '"')
              ++(*i);
            return (j);
          }
      }
  return (-1);
}

static char     *my_wordcpy(char *tab, char *str, int *i, char *sep)
{
  int           quote;
  int           j;

  j = -1;
  quote = 0;
  while (str[++(*i)] != '\0')
    if (str[*i] == '"' && quote == 0)
      quote = 1;
    else if (quote == 1 || (quote == 0 &&
                        is_cinside(sep, str[*i]) == 0 && str[*i] != '\t'))
  {
    tab[++j] = str[*i];            /* here is the invalid write. */
    if ((quote == 1 && str[*i + 1] == '"') ||
        (quote == 0 && (is_cinside(sep, str[*i + 1]) == 1 ||
                        str[*i + 1] == '\t' || str[*i + 1] == '\0')))
      {
        if (quote == 1 && str[*i + 1] == '"')
          ++(*i);
        tab[++j] = '\0';
        return (tab);
      }
  }
  return (NULL);
}

char            **my_quotetowordtab(char *str, char *sep)
{
  char          **tab;
  int           words;
  int           i;
  int           j;
  int           k;

  i = -1;
  j = -1;
  k = -1;
  if (str == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  words = count_words(str, sep);
  if ((tab = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (words + 1))) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  while (++i < words)
    {
      if ((tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (my_wordlen(str, &j, sep) + 1)))
          == NULL)
            return (NULL);
      tab[i] = my_wordcpy(tab[i], str, &k, sep);
    }
  tab[i] = NULL;
  return (tab);
}
```

Comment: Can you put an if case in your code (an assert) that check to make sure the value in `j` after increment and that `*i` is also valid and is still within the `tab` and `str` arrays?  The only way the write is invalid is if `j` is out of bounds, if `tab` is garbage, of `*i` is out of bounds, or if `str` is garabge.

Comment: Well, I don't think it is going out of bounds since I malloc the right amount with the return of the my_wordlen function (which is the same function except that it doesn't copy but just count the characters) and I also tried to malloc a lot more (+ 1000) to expand the bounds but it doesn't work. I still have that memory corruption crash. What do you mean by tab is garbage?

Comment: tab as garbage would be a bad pointer passed into the function, though the odds of that are very low if the above code is indeed the only way into your functions.

Comment: Placing an if check on `j` would 100% answer the issue of a bad index, though I still think you have an issue with quotes as I stated below.

Comment: Yes it would, but the thing is that I am limited by a coding style and I can't send more than 4 parameters to a function and I already have 4 in this one. So I don't really see how could I place a good check without sending the lenght of tab :-/

Comment: Thinking more as a temporary debug feature to try and find this issue.  If this is production level code that cannot report or assert, then I'll think of something else.  BTW, the 4 param thing is kinda silly for something like this, but I understand working under constraints :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my_wordlen` can return `-1` and you don't check this before giving it to `malloc`. In this case `0` bytes are allocated  hence in `my_wordcopy` a heap-buffer-overflow occurs.

Comment: Wow thank you, how could I not see that before?! That seem to have fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you have a `str` with only a single or odd number of `"` quote characters? Seems like your code won't check for `\0` in that case and therefore it could write passed the end of tab. I think you need to move your `NUL` character check outside of the 2nd if clause to catch both cases.

Comment: I don't know if the quotes are the problem here, I haven't pasted it here but I have a function that I call in the begining (in count_words) that check if I have a correct number of quotes. (Moving the check would be a second security though, so I am going to do it anyway, thank you)

Comment: This answer does not appear to provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that this wasn't the main answer, but it was the best answer at the time and did end up showing a potential problem.  This is not a critique nor a request for clarification.